# «Кусок» и отношение

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, олимпиада

На нижегородской олимпиаде 2019 года предлагалась следующая задача:

Существуют ли такие натуральные числа a и b, в десятичной записи каждого из которых есть кусок подряд стоящих цифр 2019 и при этом отношение a:b=2019?

Найти какую-нибудь такую пару нетрудно. Например, 201900001 и 407636102019. Однако меня заинтересовала наименьшая такая пара. И если верить Питону (а как можно ему не верить?), это числа 10002019 и 20194076361.

Одна лишь загвоздка: код работает ну из рук вон медленно.

```
# К задаче "«Кусок» и отношение"
 
kusok=int(input())
otn=int(input())
k=1
while (str(k).find(str(kusok))==-1
    or str(otn*k).find(str(kusok))==-1):
        k+=1
print(k, otn*k)
```

Можно ли изменить этот код так, чтобы программа работала быстрее?

P. S. Кстати, Если в условии задачи заменить 2019 на номер текущего года (2022), то ответ будет аналогичным: 10002022 и 20224088484. А вот для следующего года уже не так: не 10002023 и 20234092529, а 9492023 и 19202362529. Любопытно, имеются ли там какие-то закономерности?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидная оптимизация - работать с числами, а не со строками, и перебирать не все числа, а генерировать только меньшие числа, содержащие 2019

Пример для демонстрации подхода, он не выполняет правильный обход по возрастанию (что по уму следует сделать, как и отменить ограничение длины), однако работает мгновенно:

```
year = 2023
smallest = 999999999
for leftlen in range(5):
    leftmax = 10**leftlen
    for rightlen in range(5 - leftlen):
        rightmax = 10**rightlen
        for left in range(leftmax):
            l = left * 10**(4+rightlen) + year * 10**rightlen
            for right in range(rightmax):
                small = l  + right
                large = small * year
                while large >= year:
                    if large % 10000 == year:
                        smallest = min(small, smallest)
                        break
                    large //= 10
print(smallest, smallest * year)

>>9492023 19202362529
```

Comment: @Komdosh, Каков вопрос - таков ответ

Answer (score 3):

Непонятно, есть ли закономерности, но при минимальной оптимизации для 6 лет считается за 12 секунд в Google Colab:

```
for x in range(2019, 2025):
    part = ratio = x
    part_str = str(part)
    for i in range(part + 1, 1_000_000_000):
        if part_str in str(i):
            if part_str in str(i * ratio):
                print(part, i, i * ratio)
                break
```

Вывод:

```
2019 10002019 20194076361
2020 202001 408042020
2021 2021534 4085520214
2022 10002022 20224088484
2023 9492023 19202362529
2024 10002024 20244096576
```

Оптимизации тривиальные:

- То, что можно вынести за цикл, нужно вынести за цикл. Тут это преобразование в строку искомого куска.
- Вместо поиска индекса через `.find` искать вхождение строки через `in`, я проверил, это действительно быстрее раза в полтора.